# What does this mouse pad outline plastic tube made of?

Tags: lighting, led, materials

A friend of mine got me a mouse pad simular to this one Amazon.com: [https://www.amazon.com/RGB-Mousepad-Led-Mouse-Large/dp/B08QFB5KVS/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08QFB5KVS)

I noticed it has this tube in the outline (the glowy part). i want to know that type of tube is it, and whats it called? as it could be used to make glowy outline to other things other than mouse pads.

[image]

Comment: google `light pipe` ... the picture you posted is missing the light source

Comment: @jsotola yup that's what i'm looking for

Comment: I think that the video on the amazon website is probably misleading ... the edge of the mousepad cannot show more than one color at a time

Comment: You're right only two colors from the ends then it blend in the middle

Comment: lol ... forgot about two ends ... it can display only two colors at most

Comment: Whatever it is called, "glowy tube" is a better name.

Comment: Reminds me of the story where an architect called up Gene Roddenberry and said "Where do I get those automatic "Shi-shook" doors like are on Star Trek (Original Series)?  Roddenberry had to explain it was 2 crew members behind the set pulling the doors open by hand.  In this case the plastic is just a light pipe. The LEDs are actually under the mouse pad.

Comment: `light pipe` will probably turn up very expensive options, @jsotola. However, if one is dedicated to the theory that "each LED adds 5 MFLOP to processing power" then no expense is too great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling i think it could be `PMMA Plastic`

- Example1: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10697
- Example2: [https://www.amazon.com/16-5ft-Plastic-Optic-Source-0-10in/dp/B07RDJDT8B](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RDJDT8B)

More about it: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_tube#Optical_fiber

Comment: pretty much any transparent plastic can be used, even clear fish-tank hose filled with water will work.

Answer (score 0):

EL Wire. Though some might use other technologies.

Comment: I just googled EL Wire, a bit different from this one, this one has no wires, only what seems to be plastic tube and a filling of more plastic, Thanks anyway.